# jQuery cycle plugin

Tags: jquery, cycle

So i found a little bug that seems to be valid, but i cant figure out how to correct it.

It seems as though the jQuery cycle is counting the h2 and the p tags as child elements of .slideshow, and creating a link in the mininav that is generated... so instead of just 2 child elements .slide, it is displaying 4?? both in firefox and chrome... IE displays just the 2.

So is there a way to modify the script to only count the first child element of .slideshow?

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        $('.slideshow')
        .before('<div id="mininav" class="mininav" />')
        .cycle({

            fx      : 'fade',
            speed   : 'fast',
            timeout : 5500,
            pause   : 1,
            pager   : '#mininav',
            before  : function() { if (window.console) console.log(this.src); }

        });


    });
    </script>

    <div class="slideshow">             

            <div class="slide" style="background:#fff url({iw_value name='slideshow.image'/}) no-repeat top left;">

                        <h2>{iw_value name='slideshow.headline'/}</h2>
                        <p>{iw_value name='slideshow.text'/}</p>            

            </div>

<div class="slide" style="background:#fff url({iw_value name='slideshow.image'/}) no-repeat top left;">

                        <h2>{iw_value name='slideshow.headline'/}</h2>
                        <p>{iw_value name='slideshow.text'/}</p>            

            </div>

            </div><!--/slideshow-->
```

Comment: I use this exact same structure (with a few more elements), and it works fine for me. Is there some page we can look at where you have reproduced this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 'slideExpr' option in cycle? This allows you to select which child elements should be treated as slides.

Also, I recommend that you double check that the page validates just to make sure that something isn't off with the structure of .slide divs.

Comment: Everything seems to be validating just fine... i just did a little test, and commented out the <h2> and <p> tags within the .slide DIV. and all browsers display correctly.  So i just commented out the <p> tag and left the <h2> tag to display.  Worked great on all browsers.  When i displayed the <p> tag, is when i get the additional navigation elements that show blank content... why would just the <p> tag create this? I cant figure this out.

Comment: I also tried using the slideExpr: 'div.slide', variable to set it to only count the slide DIV and this does not work... it only seems to freak out when i display the <p> tag...???